# Wordpress Atom Feed - Only get entries that have been updated in the past 2 days

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to do this? I'm aware of filtering by published date, where you add to the URL a date, month, and year parameter. However, I'd like to instead filter by updated date, so even old blog posts that have been recently updated will be rendered in the feed. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *finally* figured this out.

Given you're trying to pull out Wordpress entries and you'd like to order them by a field other than published date, you can add the **orderby** parameter to the URL. It takes a variety of potential ordering types, but the one I needed was **modified**. So, for example, if you have this feed:

http://en.blog.wordpress.com/?feed=atom

and you would like to display entries ordered by modified date, you'd write the url as follows:

http://en.blog.wordpress.com/?feed=atom&orderby=modified&order=DESC